# Overflow not helping hide the flowing links

Tags: css

Here I've got a jquery menu which is working perfectly. But Ive given it a fixed width of 400px and so what happens is that if I add more than certain number of links to the main ul they will flow in the next line and that is absolutely not desired.

I tried `overflow:hidden` and `line-height` to somehow overcome the issue BUT NO RESULT anyway.

Here is the menu : http://jsfiddle.net/b5Wdc/

As you see there, the red color link flows on the next line and that is the problem.

What do should I write to hide the overflown links in this situation?

Thank you all anyway.

Comment: Is there a reason you're floating your list items to get them on one line rather than simply giving them `inline-block` or similar `display`? It's probably also worth noting that specifying both `float` and `display` on the same element is pointless as floated elements are treated as block elements regardless.

Comment: On which element did you try adding `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: @andyb, Main container and main ul. Though I knew these efforts are logically wrong because then the sub-menu ULs couldn't be displayed due to use of overflow.

Comment: @James Donnelly, thank you for adding the points. But I should mention that the menu is used for my language and that is why its right aligned using float and I agree, using display and float together is wrong. My mistake!

Comment: If you have a fixed width of `400px`, what is the use case for adding more items since they will never be displayed?

Comment: @andyb, This menu is dynamic and in case the admin adds extra links, then what wouldn't look well. I just want to prepare for that situation.

Comment: OK, I understand, thanks for clarifying. So if the admin adds extra links, what do you want to happen to those links? I see that currently they drop to the next line which is not desired but where should they go? If you hide them with some sort of `overflow:hidden` then the admin might be confused as to where the new links are.

Comment: To hide them anyway. I've already told them that you better do not add more than some certain number of links. But as few people will be managing the website rather than a single admin,perhaps I should beforehand hide the extra links in case there is any.

Answer (score 1):

if you change your styles to the following i think it may work:

```
.HeadMenu .HeadMenuMain
{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    width:400px;
    padding:0;
    direction:rtl;
    height:40px;
    white-space:nowrap; //will make elements stay on one row
}

.HeadMenu .HeadMenuMain li
{
    display:inline-block; //will make elements stay on one row with the nowrap
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5Wdc/2

Comment: that's your original code - I just added the white-space:nowrap; plus if you're going to have a go at people for trying to fix your code you can do it yourself in future

Comment: My mistake. I've written the codes wrongly here. I'll correct that.

Answer (score 1):

From our conversation in the comments on the question, it seems that your menu is completely fixed and any "extra" items should always be hidden and there is no dynamic display or wrapping required. So you can just use CSS to hide all menu items that you know won't fit in. Since a menu item has a width of `99px` and the menu is `400px` you know you will only ever show 4 items. This purely CSS will hide the rest:

```
.HeadMenu #nav > li:nth-child(n+5) {
    display:none;
}
```

However it requires a minimum of IE8 for the [`nth-child`](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) CSS selector support.

Since you mentioned jQuery in the question you could accomplish the same in JavaScript if you need to support IE8 with:

```
$('.HeadMenu #nav > li:nth-child(n+5)').hide()
```

Alternatively, keep the CSS solution (as it's cleaner) and use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to bring `nth-child` selector support to IE8.

Comment: good CSS3 solution. but I always design my websites for IE 7+ and that is the problem Andy.

Comment: selectivizr will work for IE6+ but of course there is the dependency on another JavaScript library. That said, you are using jQuery anyway, so could still use jQuery to hide the elements. Sorry, I can't think of a pure CSS solution that would work in IE7

Comment: May I suggest editing your question, stating that you don't want JavaScript solutions, so others don't waste time suggesting them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an overflow:hidden to the navigation menu will do the trick:

```
.HeadMenu #nav {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Really? It works for me in FF and Chrome. You want to keep the red element hidden from the menu, right? [Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5Wdc/4/)

Comment: That will also hide the drop downs

Comment: @Rob, Yes. to only hide " menu5 " or in fact the flowing links.